# Implementation of user beans hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, javabeans

Please tell me how to implement this idea:

I write a program for my graduate work (using Spring Framework). At the first stage, I want to create a user registration. I created Java Beans. Moreover, their variables are repeated (name, email, and some more). In order not to duplicate the code, I did so far:

**UML diagram link**

[image]

In the class constructor do so:

```
public class Observer extends User {

@Getter
@Setter
private String firstname;

@Getter
@Setter
private String lastname;

@Getter
@Setter
private Integer age;

public Observer(String email, String password, String firstname, String lastname, Integer age) {
    super.email = email;
    super.password = password;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Am I moving in the right direction? Maybe there are more convenient options? Share your experience in order to avoid code duplication? Or, can make the interfaces of each role? And how, in that case, keep everything in the database?

All in advance I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Are all fields mandatory (for User & Organization)?

Comment: for User - of couse. Organization - i think no. Variable 'website', for example, not a mandatory

Comment: To tell you the truth, these are not all classes variables. If you want to help, I can make a complete class diagram